# PostgreSQL - Combining result-rows from multiple queries

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having trouble adding two columns together which are from the same table.column, with two different values.

How do I add the following two queries together to give two new columns with each their own value;

```
SELECT
    ... more columns ...
    components.description,
FROM
    ...
WHERE
    graphiccards.id = systems.id AND
    components.id = graphiccards.component_id;

SELECT
    components.description
FROM
    ...
WHERE
    components.id = mainboards.component_id AND
    mainboards.id = systems.mainboard_id
```

I would like these two results to be on the same row in two different columns.

https://gyazo.com/de8100b645d6e0ccad3d1ec664907246

Comment: Sample data and desired results would explain what you want to do.

Comment: The image in the link isn't very helpful. Could you describe how what the desired output **should** look like?

Comment: JOIN all 4 tables with LEFT JOIN then use 2 `CASE WHEN you conditions THEN components.description END` for your columns

Comment: @Tommy Olsen to do so you need to specify join condition for your 2 selects (which row of the 1st select corresponds to which row in the 2d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may wish to look at the `UNION` operator

```
select
  components.description
  stuff as second_column
from mytable where conditions

union

select
  components.description
  stuff2 as second_column
from mytable2 where conditions2
```

You just need to make sure you have the same nr of columns with the same name.